# display resultset from oracle 10g stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, resultset, plsqldeveloper

I am using PL/SQL Developer and i have written a procedure to run a report and i need to procedure to output the resultset.

The procedure accepts input parameters and needs to output the resultset.

I cannot use a view because the procedure calls several APIs which accept the parameters i am passing into the procedure.

I understand from alot of searching that it's possible using ref_cursor but i cannot get ti to work.

A simplified version of the procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE IFSINFO.SHORTAGE_SHEET (vSite     IN VARCHAR2,
                                                    vBuyer    IN VARCHAR2,
                                                    vSupplier IN VARCHAR2,
                                                    vCursor   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)   
AS                                                    
BEGIN
    OPEN vCursor FOR                   
        SELECT blah blah blah blah blah blah;
END;
```

I have tried to execture the procedure and display the resultset using:

```
BEGIN
    vsite       := 'S03';
    vbuyer      := 'AW';
    vsupplier   := '%';    
    vcursor     refcursor;

    IFSINFO.SHORTAGE_SHEET(vsite => :vsite,
                           vbuyer => :vbuyer,
                           vsupplier => :vsupplier,
                           vcursor => :vcursor);                           
    print vcursor;                           
END;
```

And also:

```
variable rc refcursor; 
exec IFSINFO.SHORTAGE_SHEET('S03','AW','TQ1',:rc2); 
print rc2
```

But neither work. please can someone advise i am at my wits end.

Thank you
Rob

Comment: You should add the oracle tag, this is not specific to 10g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the bottom of this in pl/sql developer, the code is as follows.

Create a object to store the resultset

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ABC.TEST_TYPE
AS OBJECT
( 
  "Site"                       VARCHAR2(25),
);
```

Create a type as a table of he above object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ABC.TEST_COL 
    AS TABLE OF ABC.TEST_TYPE
```

Create a package to excute the SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC.TEST_RPT AS
    FUNCTION get_report(vPart     VARCHAR2,
                        vBuyer    VARCHAR2,
                        vSupplier VARCHAR2) RETURN ABC.TEST_COL 
    PIPELINED;
END;
```

Create the package body to excute the SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ABC.TEST_RPT AS
  FUNCTION get_report(vPart     VARCHAR2,
                      vBuyer    VARCHAR2,
                      vSupplier VARCHAR2) RETURN ABC.TEST_COL 
    PIPELINED IS
    CURSOR cTest(vPart     VARCHAR2,
                 vBuyer    VARCHAR2,
                 vSupplier VARCHAR2) IS

          SELECT Site
            FROM table
           WHERE Part = vPart
             AND Buyer = vBuyer
             AND Supplier = vSupplier;



  BEGIN
    FOR part_rec IN cTest(vSite, vBuyer, vSupplier) LOOP
      PIPE ROW(ABC.TEST_TYPE(part_rec.Site));

    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
    CLOSE cTest;
  END;
END;
```

The code to excute and output the resultset

SELECT * FROM TABLE(ABC.TEST_RPT.get_report('','',''))

Answer (score 2):

Is there an error that you see when you execute this procedure or run it in SQLPLUS?
Can you post your sqlplus session as is?

PRINT is a sqlplus specific command and it cannot be called inside the procedural block. If you need to print the results of a refcursor inside a procedure , then you'll need to fetch from it and print each record in the format that you need.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test_REFCURSOR (
  2     i_number in number,
  3     o_cursor out sys_refcursor) 
  4  as
  5  begin
  6     open o_cursor for
  7        'select empno, ename from emp
  8             where rownum < ' || i_number ;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> variable rc refcursor;
SQL> exec test_refcursor(5, :rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
```

You should also change your procedure (or) the procedure call to have different variable names.generallt, I prefix all input variables with "i_" and all output variables with "o_". This way, your procedure declaration would look like..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE IFSINFO.SHORTAGE_SHEET (i_Site     IN VARCHAR2,
                                                    i_Buyer    IN VARCHAR2,
                                                    i_Supplier IN VARCHAR2,
                                                    o_Cursor   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS ....
```

and the procedure call would be..

```
IFSINFO.SHORTAGE_SHEET(    i_site     => vsite,
                           i_buyer    => vbuyer,
                           i_supplier => vsupplier,
                           o_cursor   => vcursor);
```

You need not use the ":" in the beginning for these variables since they are not host environment variables ( this is the case for your second execution using SQLPLUS where you use the sqlplus variable "rc" inside the procedure call)

Comment: I am not using SQL PLus, i am using PL/SQL Developer, unfortunately in this instance i am unable to use SQL plus.

Comment: there is no error when i run it in pl/sql developer it just doesn't output anything.

Comment: It looks like the "set serveroutput on" setting is not on for your pl/sql developer. You can put "set serveroutput on" in the Login.sql script in directory where PL/SQL Developer is and restart it to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Sql Plus to execute this. First, define a Sql Plus refcursor.

`variable vcursor refcursor`

Next, execute an anonymous pl/sql block. Notice the `declare` keyword.

```
DECLARE
          vsite       := 'S03';
          vbuyer      := 'AW';
          vsupplier   := '%';
          -- do not declare this, use sql plus bind var     vcursor     refcursor;
BEGIN

       IFSINFO.SHORTAGE_SHEET(vsite => vsite, -- no colon
              vbuyer =>    vbuyer,
              vsupplier => vsupplier,
              vcursor   => :vcursor); 
END;
/
```

Then run this sql plus command.

`print vcursor`

print is not pl/sql

Comment: Note that the solution Rajesh posted is simpler. The exec command creates a minimal pl/sql block which should be adequate for this example.

Comment: I am not using SQL PLus, i am using PL/SQL Developer, unfortunately in this instance i am unable to use SQL plus.

Answer (score 0):

Your ref cursor variable is `rc`. But then you use `rc2`.

Change `rc2` to `rc` and it should work