# PLS-00201 Error when running stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I Recently moved on oracle database for one of my project. I have created a stored procedure for selecting multiple rows from database. Following is my procedure

```
create Or replace
PROCEDURE TEST(p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS

BEGIN
open p_cursor FOR select * from branch_info;
END TEST;
```

when I execute this procedure I got following error:

```
      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SAURAV.TEST' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I have searched for it and found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577490/calling-oracle-pl-sql-pls-00201-identifier-001-must-be-declared) but error line and reason are different.

Anyone please help me in solving this.

**EDIT:** Misprint TEST with TEXT

Comment: What is `SAURAV.TEXT`? Tablename.columnname? What if when you run `select * from branch_info;` Any errors?

Comment: @Polppan Its SAURAV.TEST, it is dbname.procedurename. If I run this command on sql editor it works fine and give me result set. I have corrected the misprint.

Comment: If `SAURAV` is a user or schema or table or view make sure you have permission to access it. Without much knowledge of what is `branch_info` it would be difficult.

Comment: well SAURAV is database schema name and I have full permission to it. However branch_info is table name in schema SAURAV.

Comment: If you are getting results from sql editor, then from where you are getting the errors?

Comment: I am getting error when I try to run stored procedure name TEST which contain this statement.

Comment: Can you describe `branch_info`?

Comment: @Polppan branch_info is table in schema named saurav, I am not getting why are you confused with 'brranch_info'

Comment: Try some name other than `TEST` and see.

Comment: @Polppan I have tried your suggestion with procedure named 'NTTEST' but getting same error with the 'NTTEST' in place of 'TEST'

Comment: Adittya See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with keyword test

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test (p_cursor OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_cursor FOR
        SELECT  *
          FROM  branch_info;
END test;
```

and execute by

```
variable rc refcursor;

exec test( :rc );

print rc;

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TEST' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Change to some other name

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test2 (p_cursor OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_cursor FOR
        SELECT  *
          FROM  branch_info;
END test2 ;
```

execute as

```
variable rc refcursor;

exec test2 ( :rc );

print rc;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

From sql plus

```
SQL> variable usercur refcursor;
SQL> DECLARE
  2  BEGIN
  3  test2(:usercur);
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print usercur;
```

Comment: do we have any other command for printing result in query editor of sql plus

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376044/display-resultset-from-oracle-10g-stored-procedure) may help

Comment: Well have you tried it on command line, I am still getting same issue there.